# How to create a dynamic layout in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

i want to write a flutter app that is completely dynamic. That means that I can define how the app should look on the server. Whether you should have a top area that I can fill dynamically with widgets. Does anyone have an idea how this can best be implemented in flutter?

An example for a server response would be:

```
{
    area: top,
    columns: 3
    rows: 5,
    items: [
        position: {
            row: 2
            column: 3
        }
        type: button,
        event: event
    ]
}, {
    area: left,
    width: 20%,
    rows: 5,
    items: [
        .....
    ]
}
```

That is only an idea how the response could look like.

Comment: there exists two appoach one is Html and another is Dynamic widget, both are available in pub, this is the second time i'm seeing the same topic question today

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're heading for something disparagingly called the "inner system" effect, where you want to write code that interprets data as if it were more code.  Please don't.